# AS3 Interactive Story Choice Button

Tags: actionscript-3, events, button, mouse, movieclip

I'll admit, I am a n00b in AS3. My question is this. I'm making an interactive novel, where I'm using movieClip as choice buttons because they offer a bit more control. I am trying to get them to respond to mouse events so that it becomes more responsive to the user (like a highlight) by going to another frame inside the movieClip of the ChoiceBtn's. This is the code I came up with and flash is acting like it does not exist.

```
ChoiceBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouse_Over);
ChoiceBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouse_Down);
ChoiceBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouse_Out);

ChoiceBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouse_Over);
ChoiceBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouse_Down);
ChoiceBtn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouse_Out);

ChoiceBtn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouse_Over);
ChoiceBtn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouse_Down);
ChoiceBtn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouse_Out);

function mouse_Over (event: MouseEvent):void 
{
    event.target.gotoAndStop(2);
}

function mouse_Down (event: MouseEvent):void 
{
    event.target.gotoAndStop(3);
}

function mouse_Out (event: MouseEvent):void 
{
    event.target.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly good. What do you mean "...flash is acting like it does not exist." What is the IT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly good.  You HAVE given your buttons instance names: ChoiceBtn1, ChoiceBtn2 and ChoiceBtn3 in the properties panel, right? What do you mean "...flash is acting like it does not exist." What is the IT?

Comment: Well, when I run the code and mouse over the movie clips, nothing happens. No highlight, or down arrow thing, nothing.

Comment: You're showing your code, but your code isn't the problem. How about showing a screen shot of your stage; another of the timeline of one of your button- MovieClips; and another of the properties panel with one of the MovieClips selected.

Comment: Also, put a trace statement inside your mouse_Over function. Like this:   trace("this function works")     Now run code. Do you get the trace in the output panel? If yes, then you've a problem with the timeline of your movieClips. If no, well that's not possible if you've named your movieClips correctly

Comment: Hey, so I took your advice and I looked at how it was setup on the timeline, and that was the problem. Thanks for your help.